# How to fetch value and key from an array which contain specific letter using php

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

I need to find the key and the value from an array that contains a specific letter without using the loop.

for Eg

```
$animal= array('lion','elephant','tiger');
```

I need to fetch the key and  value which contain 'io'

output :

```
0 - lion
```

Comment: `$animal= ('lion','elephant','tiger');` isn't valid PHP. Did you mean `$animal= ['lion','elephant','tiger'];` perhaps? If so, then this is not a new problem - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944824/search-a-php-array-for-partial-string-match (and several others)

Comment: In general, you can't search in a list without using a loop. Even if it is not visible in *plain sight*, somewhere in the process a loop will be involved.

Answer (score 0):

use array_walk function. this function will apply user-defined callback function to each element of the array

```
$animal= ['lion','elephant','tiger','lions'];

array_walk($animal, function($value, $key) use (&$array)
{
        if(strpos($value,'io') !== false)
        $array[$key]= $value;
});

var_dump($array);
```

it give output:

```
Array ( 
[0] => lion 
[3] => lions )
```

Comment: Sorry, but if there is an `animal` start with `io` it will not be stored in `$array`, since the `strpost` return the first occurrence of that char in string which is `0`, and we know `if(0)` will not be executed. So just add `!== false`. could you see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` with option `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH`

```
$animal = array('lion','elephant','tiger');
$search = 'io';
$res = array_filter($animal, function($v, $k) use($search){
  return strpos($v, $search);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/bdDSF

Comment: Same notice, I gave to @Artier, please do a test for `strpos($v, $search) !== false`, to include if there is an *animal* start with `io`.

Answer (score 0):

loop over array with `foreach` and use a test `strpos($value, $search) !== false`, Which means `$search` exist in `$value`, So take position of it which is `$key` with its value, store them in `$array`. or just show them immediately *(uncomment the echo line).*

```php
$animal = array('lion','elephant','tiger','ions');
$array = [];
$search = 'io';
foreach ($animal as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value, $search) !== false){
        $array[$key] = $value;
        //echo $key." - ".$value."<br>";
    }
}
```

**Results*:*

```php
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." - ".$value."<br>";
}
```

**Output*:*

```
/*
0 - lion
3 - ions
*/
```